# Overwrite HTML width property with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to overwrite the HTML property width of a table *without using CSS classes* in CSS?

I tried something like this without any luck:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="180">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#f0f0f0">
                <img style="display:block;" border="0" src="menu_up.jpg" alt=" " width="20" height="64">
            </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    td[width=180] {
        width: 100px !important;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You just need to select the `table` and not the `td` and you should put the value of the width attribute in quotes (just tried it out).

```
table[width="180"] {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` isn't necessary to achieve the goal, so don't use it.

Answer (score 3):

1. The value in a CSS attribute selector has to be quoted.
2. Use `table` instead of `td`.

The following worked as intended in Firefox 9.0.1 (http://jsfiddle.net/WsbP6/).

```
table[width="180"] {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Without quotes, the following error appears in my console:

> Expected identifier or string for value in attribute selector but found '180'.
>   Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, you just target the wrong thing, instead of td {}, try table {}:

http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/msgtG/

Comment: Important he just want to apply this on the tables with the current width of 180px